# VBA - Resolving Variables in a Loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm using VBA to pull excel books from a SharePoint and save them in a specified folder, and I have about 11 analysts whose workbooks I need to pull. I would rather not copy/paste the formula I'm using 11 times, so I'm trying to store their name's in variables and then use a loop. I can't seem to get it to work right though.

Here's a sample of what I have so far:

```
    Sub DownloadTimeTrackers()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Name1 As String
Dim Name2 As String
Dim Name3 As String

Name1 = "Barb"
Name2 = "Alex"
Name3 = "Cole"

For i = 1 To 3 Step 1

Const strUrl As String = "mypath\Secured\Name(i) Time Tracker.xlsm"
Dim strSavePath As String
Dim returnValue As Long

 strSavePath = "C:\Users\lxys\Desktop\TimeTrack\Name(i) Time Tracker.xlsm"
 returnValue = URLDownloadToFile(0, strUrl, strSavePath, 0, 0)

Next I

End Sub
```

I excluded some code that assists in pulling the report from SP, but I don't believe it's relevant for this..

If I substitute Name(i) for the actual name "Barb", the formula works fine, and saves to my desktop folder.

How do I get Name(i) to substitute for Barb, Alex, Cole, etc? I've tried Namei, Name + i, and Name(i) with no luck. Any suggestions why this doesn't seem to resolve correctly? I don't get any errors.

**EDIT:**

Based on feedback, I changed my program to the below, but I receive a "Subscript Out of Range" Error:

```
    Sub DownloadTimeTrackers()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Name() As Variant
Dim strUrl As String

Name = Array("Barb", "Alex", "Cole", "Cim", "Adam", "Lane", "Kristin", "Mike", "Nicki", "George", "Lori")


For i = 1 To 11 Step 1

        strUrl = "\\collab.sfcollab.org@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\WSS005469\DisputeTeam\Secured\" & Name(i) & "Time Tracker.xlsm"

Dim strSavePath As String
Dim returnValue As Long

 strSavePath = "C:\Users\fip1\Desktop\TimeTrack\" & Name(i) & "Time Tracker.xlsm"
 returnValue = URLDownloadToFile(0, strUrl, strSavePath, 0, 0)

Next i



End Sub
```

**I found the error, I didn't have a space in " Time Tracker.xlsm"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
Dim Name1 As String
Dim Name2 As String
Dim Name3 As String

Name1 = "Barb"
Name2 = "Alex"
Name3 = "Cole"
```

use

```
Dim Name() As Variant
Name = Array("Barb", "Alex", "Cole")
```

This creates an "array" of names that can be indexed by your variable `i`.  Note that this array will be zero-based by default, i.e. the first position will be `Name(0)`

---

You also need to change

```
Const strUrl As String = "mypath\Secured\Name(i) Time Tracker.xlsm"
```

to

```
Dim strUrl As String
strUrl = "mypath\Secured\" & Name(i) & " Time Tracker.xlsm"
```

(you can't have a "constant" which has varying values)

---

And change

```
strSavePath = "C:\Users\lxys\Desktop\TimeTrack\Name(i) Time Tracker.xlsm"
```

to

```
strSavePath = "C:\Users\lxys\Desktop\TimeTrack\" & Name(i) & " Time Tracker.xlsm"
```

---

Your refactored code would be

```
Sub DownloadTimeTrackers()
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim returnValue As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Name() As Variant

    Name = Array("Barb", "Alex", "Cole")

    For i = LBound(Name) To UBound(Name)

        strUrl = "mypath\Secured\" & Name(i) & " Time Tracker.xlsm"
        strSavePath = "C:\Users\lxys\Desktop\TimeTrack\" & Name(i) & " Time Tracker.xlsm"
        returnValue = URLDownloadToFile(0, strUrl, strSavePath, 0, 0)

    Next i

End Sub
```

(I also changed your loop to go from the lower bound of the array to the upper bound.  That way you can add extra names to the array and not have to worry about changing the `For` statement.)

Comment: This is good, but I get a "Subscript out of Range" error, I don't think excel is recognizing Name = Array("Barb", "Alex", "Cole")

Comment: Question : Do you have to create an array for my variable to be indexed? or could I have done it the original way i.e. Name1, Name2, etc. I'm just curious for my own understanding

Comment: @DukeLuke `Name1`, `Name2`, and `Name3` are just variable names, and could just have easily been `Name1`, `xyz`, and `myVar`.  The memory locations that they are pointing to could be at any arbitrary location.  Using an array means that VBA keeps a single memory location, and then offsets from that location (using the index) to get to the address of the value referred to.

Comment: @DukeLuke - Ahh - I just remembered that the array will be zero-based, so you will need to change your loop - I will update the answer to include some refactored code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the missing array and the path:

To loop through the names, you need them as a part of array variable, not as separate strings.

```
Dim Name() As String
Name = Array("Barb", "Alex", "Cole")
```

Then, you defined the path as a non-changing variable:

```
Const strUrl As String = "mypath\Secured\Name(i) Time Tracker.xlsm"
strSavePath = "C:\Users\lxys\Desktop\TimeTrack\Name(i) Time Tracker.xlsm"
```

The strings are always:

> "mypath\Secured\Name(i) Time Tracker.xlsm"
>
> "C:\Users\lxys\Desktop\TimeTrack\Name(i) Time Tracker.xlsm"

instead of looping through the array and evaluating as the names:

> "..." Name(0) "..."
>
> "..." Name(1) "..."

because there is no iteration of the name as the **i** is part of the text string, not an instantiation of the variable that would give you the proper member of the array. You need to put it outside the string and concatenate to it.

```
Const strUrl As String = "mypath\Secured\" & Name(i) & " Time Tracker.xlsm"

strSavePath = "C:\Users\lxys\Desktop\TimeTrack\"Name(i) & " Time Tracker.xlsm"
```